# Whats the best way to create a Smart Part in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

i kinda know how to create a Custom Web Part. But now i need to create a Smart Part.
Any idea how it works or what a easy way is to create it? Maybe some nice links to articles?

Please Help

Regards
Etienne

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a good article and sorted it out, thanks!

http://weblogs.asp.net/jan/archive/2004/11/23/268644.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Pls have a look at [Codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/smartpart), is it something like that you are looking for ?

Comment: Yes, something like that. But how to place it there is my problem.

Answer (score 0):

My web parts are created using WebUserControls. For example, you can programming all functionality in a standard asp.net application (ascx, aspx) on the same server of SharePoint and then, load the user controls in web parts and access the aspx pages copying them to layouts folder.